# Vscode can't find ts-node/register after updating to node v9

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, mocha.js, vscode-debugger

I'm suddenly getting the following error that mocha cannot find ts-node/register module when I run my tests via the VSCode debugger. This seems to have just started occurring after updating to Node v9 from v8.6 using nvm. The tests run fine when running outside of Vscode.

```
Exception has occurred: Error
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access 'ts-node/register'
at Object.fs.accessSync (fs.js:322:11)
at fs.existsSync (fs.js:343:8)
at Command.program.on.mod (/${project_path}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:267:15)
at Command.emit (events.js:185:15)
at Command.parseOptions (/${project_path}/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/commander/index.js:710:14)
at Command.parse (/${project_path}/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/commander/index.js:454:21)
at Object.<anonymous> (/${project_path}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:281:9)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:651:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
```

My tests run fine outside of VSCode using the following mocha.opts and package.json script.

```
//mocha.opts
-r ts-node/register 
-r source-map-support/register 
-u tdd 
--timeout 5000 
--colors 
build/test/**/*Test.js

//package.json
"scripts": {
  "pretest": "yarn run build",
  "test": "mocha",
```

Since updating to Node v9 using NVM I have also reinstalled yarn via `brew install yarn --without-node` as well as `yarn add ts-node -D` and `yarn add typescript -D`. I have ts-node in my node_modules/ directory.

My VSCode launch.json looks like:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Mocha Tests",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/",
  "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
},
```

When I run the tests via the debugger vscode immediately breaks on the following line with the Exception shown above:

`binding.access(pathModule.toNamespacedPath(path), mode);`

Comment: Did you launch VSCode from the workspacefolder root at the command line with "code ." ?

Comment: yes I launched VSCode from the terminal inside the workspacefolder root using 'code .'